# How to hide return value for process.stdout.write() in Nodejs REPL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, stdout, read-eval-print-loop

I'm doing some drawings in the terminal and want to hide the return value.

Example:

```
> process.stdout.write("Hello world");
Hello worldtrue
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 2 tricks in my bag that allow you to do this, based on the documentation: [Customizing REPL Output](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_customizing_repl_output)

**Trick 1**

Create a `repl.js` file with the following code:

```
require('repl').start({ prompt: '> ', writer: function myWriter() { return ''} });
```

Start your REPL with `node repl.js`
The above code uses the `writer` function to customize the output, as mentioned in the docs. You could assign the `prompt` blank as well, to further reduce the output.

**Trick 2**

Type this in your REPL

```
require('util').inspect = function () { return '' };
```

The docs hint that the `inspect` function is used to format the output, so we are replacing it with a function returning blank to silence the output.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.